# PHP how to force user to logout when the user is still logged on another computer?

Tags: php, mysql

hello i want to make system website like yahoo messenger using PHP.

here the catch: when i (as user X) logged in computer A then i logged in computer B. 
The User X in computer A must be forced to log out. 
But i don't want use session time. because user can log in every time.

Must i record to database mysql?

Thanks in advance for any help, and I'm really sorry if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you will need to store your sessions in the database.

For each request, check if the database session hasn't expired. If it has, log the user out.

Now, if a user already has an active session in the database (from another computer), invalidate/expire it. The next request on the other computer will log the user out. The sessions shouldn't collide because the new session will have a different session ID.

Comment: I have a PHP class to do just that - very simple to use.
http://social-library.org/session_wrapper.phps

Just include the class at the top of the page and make an instance. That is all that needs to be done.

Comment: What if on the same machine you got couple of different browsers. You may still want to keep those sessions alive. I would say may be its a good idea to also include I.P. addresses in equation. Off course two computers from same subnet will have one public IP i.e. routers IP but depending on how in depth you want it I will bring IPs into the equation

Comment: @JaspreetChahal: This is a good remark, thank you. Database-stored sessions typically include the IP (or at least my company does include them), so it would make sense to check it as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As said in the above post, you need to store the session in a database, you might also considering storing the user's IP address so you can be sure that the user is accessing your web app from a different machine. A different session id doesn't mean that the user is definetly accessing from a different computer, because a user might have two (or more) browsers open on the same computer.

Please also note that for capacity and performance issues IP address shouldnt be stored as x.x.x.x please read the following doc

http://www.retran.com/beej/inet_ntoaman.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

You can than clear the other sessions either by running a script when the user login (Every user will clear his own logins, on other machines), or by implementing a link ( so the user performs this task at his own demand, like in google accounts) or by running a cronjob over your script.

Hope this helps, have a nice day!